# How to get parent value of div a value

Tags: jquery, parent

I have html code:

```
<div class="top-menu">
  <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="info" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn" aria-expanded="false" >INFO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn" aria-expanded="false">MAINITEM <span class="carot"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom" role="menu">
      <li><a>A</a></li>
      <li><a>B</a></li>
      <li><a>C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I need when i click on li element (A, B or C) to get value of MAINITEM. I have around 10main items on page and need to get this MAINITEM of value.

I try using:

```
$("a.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle, ul.dropdown-menu.dropdownhover-bottom li a").on('click', function () {
  alert($(this).closest('.dropdown-toggle').find('a').text());
})
```

But i get empty result.

Comment: Have you considered using `parent`?

Comment: Please provide HTML!

Comment: You don't target the right parent... Use `.closest('.dropdown').find("a").text()`... Because `.closest('.dropdown-toggle')` is the `a` element... And not a "parent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

http://jsfiddle.net/o90wnmuL/

```
 jQuery(".dropdown li a").click(function(){
   text =  jQuery(this).closest(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").text();
   console.log(text)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `jQuery.closest()` function only filters through parent elements. Since you are combining two different selectors you should use common parent for both both target elements. In your case the common parent is `.dropdown`.

Additionally you need to make sure you are filtering through the correct `a` element because `.dropdown` can have many anchor tags. In your case you can use `a.btn`.

Below is a working example with the changes suggested above.

```js
$("a.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle, ul.dropdown-menu.dropdownhover-bottom li a").on('click', function(e) {
  alert($(this).closest('.dropdown').find('a.btn').text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top-menu">
  <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="info" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn" aria-expanded="false">INFO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn zoomIn" aria-expanded="false">MAINITEM <span class="carot"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom" role="menu">
      <li><a>A</a></li>
      <li><a>B</a></li>
      <li><a>C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```